# scikit-learn GridSearchCV Deprecation Warning

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using GridSearchCV from scikit-learn 0.14, but always get the following warning:

> /Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/grid_search.py:706: DeprecationWarning: Additional parameters to GridSearchCV are ignored! The params argument will be removed in 0.15.
>     DeprecationWarning)

Does anyone knows exactly which parameters are being ignored?

The code (x and y are read from a file):

```
def balanced_accuracy (ground_truth, predictions):
    f00 = 1. * ((ground_truth == 1) & (predictions == 1)).sum() / (ground_truth == 1).sum()
    f11 = 1. * ((ground_truth == 2) & (predictions == 2)).sum() / (ground_truth == 2).sum()
    return 0.5* (f00 + f11)

bc_score = make_scorer(balanced_accuracy, greater_is_better=True)

C_range = 10. ** np.arange(-3, 3)
gamma_range = 10. ** np.arange(-3, 3)
r_range = np.concatenate((np.array([0]), 10.0 ** np.arange(-1, 3)))
kernel = "poly"
deg = 2
cw = "auto"

param_grid = dict(C=C_range, coef0 = r_range, gamma=gamma_range)
ss = ShuffleSplit(len(y), 10, test_size = 1000, train_size = 1000)

grid = GridSearchCV(svm.SVC(kernel = kernel, max_iter = 1000000, degree = deg, class_weight = cw), param_grid=param_grid, cv=ss, scoring = bc_score)
grid.fit (x, y, sample_weight = sw)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The `sample_weight` argument to `grid.fit` is deprecated. This is evident both in the docs, and by looking at the [0.14.X release branch of scikit-learn's source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.14.X/sklearn/grid_search.py#L688-L707).

In this case, the sample_weight is ignored in the 0.14 releasee as well, so `grid.fit(x, y sample_weight=sw)` is equivalent to `grid.fit(x, y)`.

As a side note, it's a good idea write in compliance with [pep-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).